# Different colors of COLOR_WINDOW in Windows 10 and Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

In Windows 10 color of window equal of background colors of GUI elements. However, in Windows XP color of window is white, that is not equal of background colors of elements.

WNDCLASSEX configuration:

```
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;
    //...
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW; // Set background color
    //...
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 1;
```

[image: Window in Windows 10]
[image: Window in Windows XP]

What is color I should use as window background in Windows XP?

Comment: Sounds like you want the dialog face color COLOR_3DFACE.

Comment: @RaymondChen, unfortunately COLOR_3DFACE is white in my WinXP too.

Comment: You must add +1 to the `COLOR_` constants when assigning them to `hbrBackground`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. `(HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE+1)` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COLOR_3DFACE`/`COLOR_BTNFACE` is the color constant you are looking for. `COLOR_WINDOW` is the color inside a text box.

[GetSysColor function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor)

> | Value | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | COLOR_3DFACE 15 | Face color for three-dimensional display elements **and for dialog box backgrounds**. |
> | COLOR_BTNFACE 15 | Face color for three-dimensional display elements **and for dialog box backgrounds**. The associated foreground color is COLOR_BTNTEXT. |

You must add `+1` to the system color constant when using it as a class brush:

[WNDCLASSEXA structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexa)
[WNDCLASSEXW structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassexw)

> `hbrBackground`
>
> Type: `HBRUSH`
>
> A handle to the class background brush. This member can be a handle to the brush to be used for painting the background, or it can be a color value. A color value must be one of the following standard system colors (**the value 1 must be added to the chosen color**). If a color value is given, you must convert it to one of the following `HBRUSH` types:

[Why do I have to add one when setting a class background brush to a system color?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20211220-00/?p=106044)

> To make sure that the result is not zero.
>
> The COLOR_SCROLL­BAR system color is index zero. If we didn’t add one to the system color indices, then an attempt to set the background color to the scroll bar color would end up with (HBRUSH)0, which is a null pointer. When the system saw that you set hbrBackground to a null pointer, it wouldn’t know whether you meant the window to have no background color (null pointer), or whether you wanted it to have the system scroll bar color (COLOR_SCROLL­BAR).